# changing page address format

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I create a website with ASP.NET web form and I used **URL friendly** to shape my URLs , by URL friendly my URLs change but not enough for example one of my page "[تور استانبول](http://tripvc.com/tours/%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84/1)" URL after changing by URL friendly is Domain.com/tours/تور-استانبول/استانبول/1 but I want Domain.com/تور-استانبول/استانبول/

please note that I don't want to query on sql to rewrite to my page and also I don't want to create static page and because my pages are dynamic I can't write all of them in web config file

please help me in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hamid, you can use asp.net routing. The following link contains explains how to do it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

hope it helps